# Is there any way of triggering Vuejs function using jQuery event trigger?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

I'm currently trying to trigger a change event inside a Vue component.

The component template contains a select element. When I'm using jQuery to trigger a change event on the element the Vue component isn't detecting it.

Example code:

```
<mycomponent></mycomponent>

<script>
    Vue.component("mycomponent", {
        template: `
            <select id="mySelect" @change="alert('detected a change')">
                <option value="0">Select color</option>
                <option value="1">Red</option>
                <option value="2">Yellow</option>
                <option value="3">Blue</option>
            </select>
        `
    });
    
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#mySelect").val(2);
        $("#mySelect").trigger("change");
    }, 5000);
</script>
```

My achievement is to trigger the VueJS event so the alert will be trigger.

**Is there any option to achieve that by triggering the event from jQuery?**

**or paraphs to trigger Vue component function from a vanilla onchange function?**

example:

```
<select id="mySelect" :onchange="MY_VUEJS_FUNCTION_GOES_HERE">
```

Thanks for your help!

---- **Why I need to combine jQuery and VueJS** ---

Some of you asked so I'll explain my main goal and why I need to combine VueJS and jQuery togheter.

I have a jQuery library that makes the selection element to be much more efficient, it basically hide the real selection and makes a div selection that is functioning in the same way. when you choose an option from the selection it updates the hidden selection.

When my selection is changed I need to get a callback so I can update other elements on my component.

right now I can't get the callback.

------ **After some research** ------

It seems that is not possible.. I'm not posting it as an answer because maybe someone out there knows a trick / a way to make it happen.

sadly the only choice I found is the rebuild the library in VueJS as a component and use it by that..

Comment: Why would you do that? Are you asking an [XY question](http://xyproblem.info)?

Comment: I always say, if you're using vuejs and jquery simultaneously, you're doing it wrong - what you want to achieve is most likely attainable without jquery - or any native DOM methods for that matter

Comment: Also, if you're using `alert`, `prompt` or `confirm` for debugging, you're also doing it wrong - console.log/.info/.warn/.error/.many others is what you use for debugging

Comment: @Bravo I've added the information to my post. I wish I could do it 100% on Vue. Would love to hear your suggestions

Comment: Are you sure that your @change event doesn't trigger? Maybe it does but you need to write 'this.alert' instead of alert

Comment: @badoyasi - I didn't ask for information, isherwood did, all I said is using two frameworks (vuejs and jquery in this case) isn't a good idea - because they NEVER play well together, and using `alert` for debugging isn't a good idea either - because alert is modal, and (not in this case) can hinder debugging rather than help it - use `console` for debugging

Comment: @Wimanicesir When using :onchange I'm able to trigger the function but only once when the page loads. It doesn't response when using jQuery trigger function. when using v-on:change the function isn't triggered at all. it will work if I'll use the built in selection that the browser generate

Comment: @Bravo I agree. it was only for the demonstration but thanks for your suggest.

Comment: as for how this can be done in vue - I can't say, because you didn't say what jquery library you're using

Comment: @Bravo It's a library that I've coded from scratch, so I can't give a link to it. but it basically does the code you can see under the setTimeout. it changes the value of the selection and then it triggers the change event.

Comment: oh, right - then maybe https://vuejs.org/v2/examples/select2.html won't help much, but it may help you create a wrapper component for your library

Comment: You should work with v-model to get the value and use a watch to detect when this value has changed. From this watch you can do whatever you want :)

Comment: @Wimanicesir Sadly I've tried it. but it didn't succeed.

Answer (score 0):

As I said, working with a v-model and a watch gives you the freedom to do what you want when the value is changed. Example below :)

```js
new Vue({
  data: {
    color: ''
  },
  watch: {
    color: function (color) {
      // Here you can write whatever code you want :)
      console.log('Color index changed to', color)
    }
 }
}).$mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
   <select id="mySelect" v-model="color">
      <option value="0">Select color</option>
      <option value="1">Red</option>
      <option value="2">Yellow</option>
      <option value="3">Blue</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but please read my question. I'm not working with the normal browser select element.  I'm using a jQuery library that is overriding the normal browser selection and hide it and generates a div. when you click on one of the div childrens(the options) it triggers an onchange event on the hidden select element. I can't detect the onchange event using VueJS. ofcourse v-model will do the work under a normal select element. you can use change event and it will work the same. a watch will do the trick also. but it doesn't relevant when you need to trigger the event from jQuery

Comment: So if I understand correctly. You have a div that has multiple divs in it that is begin used as an select. And you want to have an onchange equivalent? In that case, why doesn't a click event on the div doesn't work? I feel like I understand the problem better but still not completely..

Comment: The divs are added to the dom afterwards so the Vue don't recognize them because they are not part of the template. but even if I trigger an event on an element that is under  the template for example the hidden selection VueJs don't detect it but normal javascript like onchange does triggers. Right now I'm rebuilding the library in Vue under this conditions it will work because the component I'm building will be part of the template